# How can I call function from one csx file to another csx file in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, csx

How can we create another run.csx and call the existing function from one csx file to another in an Azure Function App?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just write another file, e.g. lib.csx and load it via `#load "lib.csx"` in your main script file. See [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp.md#reusing-csx-code) for the docs

As an example, place this into your `run.csx`

```
#load "lib.csx"

using System;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");    
    log.Info(doubleTheInt(5).ToString());
}
```

and that into a `lib.csx`

```
using System;

public static int doubleTheInt(int x) {
    return x+x;
}
```

and it should output 10 in the log

Comment: I assume "lib.csx" gets created and saved like any other .csx, but how do you indicate where it should get stored?

Comment: @RandyMinder I am not sure if I understand you correctly but `#load` can work with relative paths like `"..\shared\lib.csx"` (see e.g. the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#reusing-csx-code))